# Random number generator for python based discord bot

Tags: python, random, discord, discord.py

What I am trying to do is when someone enters the command !random (argument) I want the bot to generate a number between 1 and what they put as the argument. But whenever I try to do this it gives me around 6 different errors that are very long and make no sense to me. My current code for this command is below.

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def random1and10(ctx, number):
    arg = random.randint(1, number)
    if number:
        await Bot.say(arg)
    else:
        await Bot.say('Please select a valid number')
```

Comment: When you are assigning `arg` you are using the parameter `number` before you've checked to see if it exists with your `if` statement. First thing would be to assign `arg` within the `if`statement instead of before it. It's probably a good idea to cast the `number` input to an `int` as well, which would look like this. `random1and10(ctx, number: int):`. Beyond that, there isn't much advice someone could give without knowing the specific errors you're getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `number` is passed as a string, so:

- you need to cast it to an integer before passing it to `randint`
- probably need to cast it to a string again before "saying" it

What's more, you're not using the correct way to check for wrong integer values; `if number` will never be `False` because your `randint` call will only return integers greater than `0` (or raise an error).

---

A fixed version would be something like:

```
@Bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def random1and10(ctx, number):
    try:
        arg = random.randint(1, int(number))
    except ValueError:
        await Bot.say("Invalid number")
    else:
        await Bot.say(str(arg))
```

Your mileage may vary, I didn't run it. I'm not sure about the decorated function signature.

---

> whenever I try to do this it gives me around 6 different errors that are very long and make no sense to me.

Maybe they can make sense to others :) I'm relatively new to this site, but I think including them in your post would have been better. Cheers !